# Wordpress admin: Get current open post (order) edit page meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a website running on woocommerce and we run a custom tax solution there. On frontend everything works perfect atleast in admin as we have set, that tax is calculated by store address, we get the basic store country into all of the orders. What we are trying to achieve is to replace this country in admin from current open order post meta. But we are unlucky and we are not getting any data. Is there any possiblity to get current open post meta value?

```
function custom_base_country($base_country ){ 
if (is_admin()){
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = $_GET['post'];
    $country = get_post_meta($order->id, 'country_code', true);
    $base_country = $country;   
} 
    return $base_country;
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_countries_base_country', 'custom_base_country', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer by changing the code to `$country = get_post_meta($order, 'country_code', true);`